# Does the fruit of Mantra Japa automatically go to Indra if Japa Samarpana Mantra is not chanted?

Tags: mantras, indra, japa, punyam

Please let me know does all the mantra chanting energy go to Indra, if we don't chant the below Samarpanam mantra after mantra chanting:

Devta:

गुह्याति-गुह्य-गोप्ता-त्वं
गृहाणास्मितकृतम् जपं।
सिद्धिर्भवतु मे देवो
त्वत्प्रसादान्मयि स्थिरा ||

Devi:

गुह्याति-गुह्य-गोप्त्री-त्वं
गृहाणास्मितकृतम् जपं।
सिद्धिर्भवतु मे देवी
त्वत्प्रसादान्मयि स्थिरा ||

Comment: This is interesting where did u read about this?

Comment: I hv read a related thing that if Japa count is not kept then fruits are taken by Rakshasas but this is new for me

Comment: @Rickross I read on this blog- http://japamrit.blogspot.com/2015/02/7-samarpanam.html?m=1

Comment: @Rickross what you mean by keeping Japa count?

Comment: How many times we are doing the japa we hv to keep count of it .. either by fingers or by rosary beads

Comment: @Rickross for the same day or till the end of the body we need to keep count on how many times a mantra is chanted?

Comment: No, in each session we hv to keep count .. even if it's for 10 times we hv to keep the count using a mala or some other methods I think u already know about this

Comment: @Rickross do you know in what all the ways mantra punya or mantra energy is taken by rakshas or Devtas?

Comment: I know only abt the count .. if u do not count while chanting then u will not receive the fruits ... Rakshasas hovering around that place will enjoy the fruits .. so its ur hard work but their enjoyment ... :D Japa Samrapan shd also be done, but for that we first need to chant the Dhyana of the deity

Comment: @Rickross ok. Can you please answer my question. It would be great if you can tell is this mantra genuine

Comment: I can tell u the Japa Samarpana mantra that i use or the ones mentioned in other texts but I can not answer  what happens if it is not chanted ..

Comment: BTW the mantras u quoted and is there in the site u referred to are grammatically wrong. GihAna+asmatv =  GrihAnasmat. A meaning आ. asmat means mine

Comment: @Pratimaputra ok thanks. Can you please write the mantra in Sanskrit. Also do we need to do some action in this mantra. In that site, the person is touching the right hand with left hand and doing some action like some kind of Nyasa.

Comment: @Pratimaputra just please let me know the complete procedure of this samparpan mantra. Thank you so much

Comment: taking little amout of sacred water or sacred water with the things mentioned in the answer in right hand making gandusha, utter the mantra annd assuming Ishta's hand mentally offer it to Ishta's hand gently slanting the hand rightward. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Japa-samarpana mantras according to Shyamarahasya(page 3) for a male deity is

> guhyAtiguhya-goptA tvam grihaNasmatkrtam japam/ siddhir bhavatu me deva tvat prasAdat tvayi sthite//

For a female deity the mantra is

> guhyAtiguhyagoptri tvam grihANAsmatkritam japam/siddhir bhavatu me devi tvatprasAdAt tvayi sthite//

In some books, instead of the last two words, "Mahesvara' and 'Mahesvari' are also seen.

According to the Purascharana-chandrika, if the method of COUNTING is not followed properly, the rakshasas steal the fruits of the japa and so intelligent people must count properly:

> gaNanAvidhim ullanghya yo japet tu prmAditah/ grihnananti rAkshasAh yasmat niyatam ganayet budhah//

The counting is just for that time.Not for remembering life long.Sadhak Kamalakanta, a famous shAkata saint says

> If you protect by Your Own goodness and give a merciful grance, only then sadhana is fruitful. Getting your vision by doing japa is absurd like the marriage of the ghosts.

But that dependence and surrender is the ultimate.In the beginning, an aspirant should follow the injunctions of the scriptures to the best of his/her abilities. So the achamana, asana, place, counting, samarpana etc-- each is important. Regarding samarpana of japa, PurascharyarNava says

> evam japam pura kritva gandha-akshata-kusha-udakaih/japam samarpayed devyah vamahaste vichakshaNah// meaning that an intelligent individual should, after completing the japa, offer the japa to the left hand of Devi with sandal paste, atapa rice, kusha-grass and (sacred) water.

For Male Deity, to right hand is japa offered with sandal paste, flower,mand water as Arghya:

> kritva japam pura chaivam tejorupam samarpayet/ Devasya dakshiNe haste kusha-pushpa-arghya-vAribhih (Sanatkumara-Tantravachana)

After japa, pradakshina and then pranAmaa are also obligatory:

> tatas cha devatAm bhaktyA parikramya named budhah: YAmala-vachana.

As Sri Krishna says in the Gita

> 16.23 Ignoring the precept of the scriptures, he who acts under the impulsion of passion,-he does not attain perfection, nor happiness, nor the supreme Goal.
>
> 16.24 Therefore, the scripture is your authority as regards the determination of what is to be done and what is not to be done. After understanding (your) duty as presented by scriptural injunction, you ought to perform (your duty) here.

I never heard that the fruits 'go to Indra'! Please note than Indra is one major form of God in the Vedas.In fact, One should remember that His/Her Ishtadevata has assumed the differnt forms Himself/Herself.But to get the fruits of japa, one has to do the samarpana properly.

Only for manasa-japa, NO counting is required and it is the best of the japas.It does not need asana or restrictions on the place etc either.

(Reference: Sastramulak Bharatiya shaktisadhana,mUpendrakumar Das,RMIC, vol 2, chapter :japa)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please add the samarpana mantra in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The full process of Japa in short has the following steps:

1. Taking the Sankalpa (stating the purpose of Japa and revealing to the World that you will be doing the Japa)
2. Performing Rishi-Adi Nyasas ( 6 limbs of a mantra to be planted at their respective places on our body)
3. Doing Kara Nyasa and Anga Nyasa (for invoking divinity in our own body and for making us pure for the task)
4. Chanting the Dhyana Sloka for the particular Japa. (after this is done the Deity visits that place)
5. Do Pancha Upachara Puja using Mudras and mantras without any actual ingredients.
6. Then do the Japa as vowed.
7. Repeat Kara and Anga Nyasa.
8. Invoke Deity again by chanting Dhyana.
9. Do Pancha Upachara Puja again.

**10. Do Japa Samarpanam (submitting the Japa to the Deity).**

For this last step, the following Mantra is usually used (given in [Nityotsava's](http://www.shivashakti.com/nityot.htm) 1st Chapter, the Ganapaty Krama):

> GuhyAti-guhya-goptA tvam grihAnAs-mat-kritam japam |
>   Siddhir-bhavatu me deva tvat-prasAdAn-mayi sthirA ||
>
> Iti sAmAnyArghyodakena japam devasya dakshakare samarpitam vibhAvya
>   stubita |
>
> You are the Protector of the secret of the secrets; O Deva! please
>   accept the Japa that is done by me. By your grace may I receive Sthira
>   Siddhi (the accomplishment that is permanent).
>
> Chanting thus, one should offer the Japa to the right hand of the
>   Deity with Samanya Arghya water (any pure water will do).

Since, this is talking about Ganapaty Japa, the Mantra has Deva in it. If it is Japa of any Goddess, then simply change Deva to Devi in the Mantra. And, in this case, the Samarpana should be done on the left hand of the Devi.

When we chant the Dhyana Mantra the Deity, it is said that the Deity  graces that place with its presence. We have to imagine that the Deity is facing us. And, we have to accordingly submit the Japa to the right or the left hand.

The Mudra to be formed as follows:

Face your left palm facing up and place on it the right palm which is also facing upwards. Take a little bit of water in the right palm and chant the Samarpana Mantra and then offer it.

Now, I have never read about what happens if Japa Samarpana is not done but it is mandatory and usually part of the whole process.

Comment: For regular japa all these steps are not prescribed though

Comment: Yes may be but I m being taught to do like this @Pratimaputra

Comment: left palm on right palm? pl check!

Comment: by whom being taught?

Comment: Thanks :D that is corrected now @Pratimaputra

Comment: That is a secret @Pratimaputra

Comment: i see.Srinath or kripanath:)

Comment: Excellent answer but I've a doubt. Except for keeping the count of the japa, these procedures are not necessary when we do Nama Japa in Manasa form. Are they?

Comment: If Manasa Japa keeping count is not necessary but otherwise it should be kept @LSSJBroly

Comment: But why is that so? I mean neither the procedures are required nor keeping the count is required for Manasa Japa? Is it because we do it internally and hence there is no use of these things?

Comment: Normally it is said that keeping the count for Japa is a must ... otherwise fruits are taken by Rakshasas. But for manasa japa it is also stated that no rules, that are required otherwise, are to be followed. From this it can be said that for mental japa count may not be kept. @LSSJBroly

Comment: Also when doing Mantra Japa for Siddhi, purascharana, these rules are strictly required to be followed.. when we are mentally chanting just names while doing daily activities it is not that important to keep count.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :D

Comment: Rickross ji if we wish to keep count for 'Manasa Nama Japa' , can we do it with rosary beads or are there rules for doing it with rosary?

Comment: Count can be kept in various ways like using rosary or using finger counting method and another method is also there @LSSJBroly

Comment: Thanks but are there some rules if we do it with rosary??

Comment: @LSSJBroly Yes rules are there like don't cross the meru ... after 108 chants reverse the mala ... also cover the hand inside a bag while counting .. counting should be done using the thumb and the middle finger and the index finger should be kept out through the hole of the japa bag.

Comment: Yes yes this is what I wanted. Could you elaborate it more by providing a genuine youtube video or something here on HSE sir? Actually not able to get some of the points properly.

Comment: You can go through the following link .. if you have any further doubts you can ask (https://prabhujisgifts.com/blogs/prabhujis-gifts-blog/the-mysteries-of-the-mala) @LSSJBroly

Comment: Thanks for helping me so much 