# How should one do manasika mantra japa

Tags: mantras, japa, nama-japa

Is there any specific procedure prescribed? I have read somewhere that manasika japa isn't just mere internal chanting of the mantra.

Comment: The following answer might be useful: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18451/4732

Comment: No. It isn't helpful. Read the Question again please.

Comment: See the last blockquote of my answer. It talks about the fact that manasa japa does not have much rules associated with it.

Comment: One may follow this: first one remembers Ganesha, Guru, then recites the viniyog, performs the KarNyasa, Hridy-adi-Nyasa, recites the Dhyana mantra, performs the Manasik puja (lam ityadi puja), Does japa (be it manasik, vaschik) as convience 1 mala, 2 mala etc, again perform Hridy-adi-Nyasa, recites Dhyana mantra, performs Manasik puja and finally recites samarpanam mantra.

Comment: You may find this answer useful: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34266/21353